# Does anyone know why NISTs SHA3 256 output Hash for the 1600 bit file is different to other SHA3 256 output hashes?

Tags: sha-3

I have been trying to implement my own SHA3 256 function in python to try and learn and understand how it works. I have been comparing my hashes with an online sha3 tool found here https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html and the test files on the NIST website found here https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/example-values.

I realised that the output hash found in the 1600 bit file found on the NIST file is different from the one on the online tool. I have even used a python sha3 library and the result of the hash is the same as the one on the online tool.

Does anyone know why the NIST output hash is different? I know NIST has made some changes to SHA3 padding but I am still unsure.

Comment: This is better to be asked at [so] with your code so that one can see your errors. I've seen lots of simple errors in [so] that were corrected.

Comment: As the question is not about his code but about the nist samples vs common libraries, I think here should be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIST gave the 1600-bit input as a bit-string, with each byte in LSb first *bit* order. So `1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1` is `A3`, not `C5` as one would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I can't believe I missed something obvious.

Comment: Well, LSb first is really weird, I'd hardly call it obvious.

Comment: The above answer really solves my doubt. I search long time and finally found answer here.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Very true. Octets have better interoperability than bits, and even bytes (which used to have all kinds of sizes). The linked example file has the data blob in 8-bit bytes as well, just down below.

Comment: Endianness is historically a mess in crypto. DES was big-endian, de facto at least. MD5 was little-endian, except for bits in bytes. Smart Cards are big-endian in the original/inverse ISO 7816-3 convention for physical bit order in bytes (I believe this is accidental), and P1P2 values; _except_ when little-endian as in modern/direct ISO 7816-3 convention and Mifare/NXP UID. SHA-1, SHA-2, ECDSA hash-to-integer and field-element to integer, and ASN.1 BER/DER are uniformly big-endian.